# Multivariate analysis with lmer and lmerTest

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multivariate-analysis, manova, compositional-data

I'm dealing with compositional data (data that sum to 1). They are inherently multivariate. One way to analyse compositional data is with a ilr (isometric log-ratio) transformation. I'm following the procedure described [here](https://ijbnpa.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12966-018-0685-1) and [here](http://ndl.ethernet.edu.et/bitstream/123456789/39269/1/K.%20Gerald%20van%20den.pdf).

After an ilr transformation, it is suggested that we can uses traditional ANOVA or MANOVA analysis. I'm more interested in linear mixed models since I'm doing this for other variables. However, there is no clear explanation on how to perform a multivariate model with lme4 (`lmer`).

Reading online, I came across the following help : [From StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364683/multivariate-linear-mixed-model-using-lmer), [on Rpubs](https://rpubs.com/bbolker/3336) and on [github](https://mac-theobio.github.io/QMEE/lectures/MultivariateMixed.notes.html).

However, the explanations are unclear for people who are new to complex statistical analysis. Normally, I would create my model using lme4 and analyze it more traditionally with `lmeTest` and `emmeans`. With the help that I've found online, however, I cannot go through the classic MANOVA/ANOVA/PostHoc process. In other words ... I don't understand ''what's next''.

Here is some information about my design.
25 participants
5 trials/condition
2x2x3 design
Realized(oui, non) - between subjects
FB(GoodFB, ErroneousFB, NoFB) - Within subjects
Feet(FT, FA) - Within subjects
Compositional variable with 4 level that sum to 1 (these are frequency band contributions)
Med, Low, VL, UL

I did some tests following the [github](https://mac-theobio.github.io/QMEE/lectures/MultivariateMixed.notes.html) procedure and I arrived at a point where I just ... don't know what to do anymore.
Note, these are with the **raw** data, not the ilr transform. One thing at the time !
--> Yes I know, there is a warning. Model probably too complex.

```r
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Value ~ Bande:(FB * Feet * Realized) + (Bande - 1 | Trial) +  
    (Bande - 1 | Participant)
   Data: Wavelet2
 REML criterion at convergence: 23617.9
 Random effects:
  Groups      Name     Std.Dev. Corr             
  Participant BandeLow  4.03193                  
             BandeMed  2.92682  0.58            
             BandeUL   6.67916 -0.85 -0.66      
             BandeVL   3.45339 -0.05 -0.27 -0.36
 Trial       BandeLow  0.56382                  
             BandeMed  0.38568  1.00            
             BandeUL   1.01499 -1.00 -1.00      
             BandeVL   0.04408  1.00  1.00 -1.00
 Residual             12.76134                  
 Number of obs: 2988, groups:  Participant, 25; Trial, 5
 Fixed Effects:
                         (Intercept)                BandeLow:FBErroneousFB  
                             18.4113                               10.8568  
              BandeMed:FBErroneousFB                 BandeUL:FBErroneousFB  
                             -6.7167                               20.0527  
               BandeVL:FBErroneousFB                     BandeLow:FBGoodFB  
                              1.4899                               12.0116  
                   BandeMed:FBGoodFB                      BandeUL:FBGoodFB  
                             -7.4437                               18.4319  
                    BandeVL:FBGoodFB                       BandeLow:FBNoFB  
                              2.7916                               11.8681  
                     BandeMed:FBNoFB                        BandeUL:FBNoFB  
                             -5.4416                               19.2281  
                     BandeLow:FeetFT                       BandeMed:FeetFT  
                             -0.7688                               -5.1311  
                      BandeUL:FeetFT                        BandeVL:FeetFT  
                             -5.2262                               11.6565  
                BandeLow:Realizedoui                  BandeMed:Realizedoui  
                             -2.6386                               -2.2251  
                 BandeUL:Realizedoui                   BandeVL:Realizedoui  
                              6.1435                               -0.9827  
            BandeLow:FBGoodFB:FeetFT              BandeMed:FBGoodFB:FeetFT  
                              0.5580                                1.4025  
             BandeUL:FBGoodFB:FeetFT               BandeVL:FBGoodFB:FeetFT  
                              0.6047                               -2.6751  
              BandeLow:FBNoFB:FeetFT                BandeMed:FBNoFB:FeetFT  
                             -4.9176                               -1.0432  
               BandeUL:FBNoFB:FeetFT                 BandeVL:FBNoFB:FeetFT  
                              7.2515                               -1.2547  
       BandeLow:FBGoodFB:Realizedoui         BandeMed:FBGoodFB:Realizedoui  
                              7.3775                               12.4733  
        BandeUL:FBGoodFB:Realizedoui          BandeVL:FBGoodFB:Realizedoui  
                            -14.5717                               -5.6681  
         BandeLow:FBNoFB:Realizedoui           BandeMed:FBNoFB:Realizedoui  
                              3.5385                                5.1612  
          BandeUL:FBNoFB:Realizedoui            BandeVL:FBNoFB:Realizedoui  
                             -7.4511                               -1.5036  
         BandeLow:FeetFT:Realizedoui           BandeMed:FeetFT:Realizedoui  
                              1.0658                                3.3089  
          BandeUL:FeetFT:Realizedoui            BandeVL:FeetFT:Realizedoui  
                              1.6401                               -6.3232  
BandeLow:FBGoodFB:FeetFT:Realizedoui  BandeMed:FBGoodFB:FeetFT:Realizedoui  
                              1.4889                              -10.8614  
 BandeUL:FBGoodFB:FeetFT:Realizedoui   BandeVL:FBGoodFB:FeetFT:Realizedoui  
                              4.0406                                5.6913  
  BandeLow:FBNoFB:FeetFT:Realizedoui    BandeMed:FBNoFB:FeetFT:Realizedoui  
                             -1.5140                               -6.8196  
   BandeUL:FBNoFB:FeetFT:Realizedoui     BandeVL:FBNoFB:FeetFT:Realizedoui  
                              2.0001                                6.5935  
fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / 
 coefficient
 optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK) ; 0 optimizer 
 warnings; 1 lme4 warnings
```

[image]

[image]

Now that I've done that, and I see coorelation ... what's the next step ? Is there a way to write/correct the model to perform further post-hoc analysis like I would do in a traditional MANOVA ? Should I just let it go and perform multiples lmer models for each of the composition (which will be ilr transformed in the future).

Any insight will be much appreciated !